# How to reshape a 32x512 into 128x128 keeping it as consistant 4 32x128 parts stacked?

Tags: python, pytorch

So I want to turn 32x512 into 128x128 keeping it as consistant 4 32x128 parts stacked like this:
[image].

How to do such a thing inside the PyTorch model?

---

So here is what I tried based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67645427/1973207):

```
import torch 
x = torch.arange(32*512*3*2).reshape(2, 3, 32, 512)
print(x.shape)

x = list(x.split(4, dim=3))
print(f" xx {len(x)} {iii.shape for iii in x }")

x = torch.cat(x)
print(f" xs {x.shape}")
```

And this outputs:

```
torch.Size([2, 3, 32, 512])
 xx 128 <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f358f1edad0>
 xs torch.Size([256, 3, 32, 4])
```

While I wanted  `xs torch.Size([2, 3, 128, 128])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use, for tensor `t`:

```
torch.cat(t.split(128, dim=1))
```

To transform in the reverse direction, you can use:

```
torch.cat(t.split(32, dim=0))
```

---

For your updated question:

```
torch.cat(t.split(128, dim=3), dim=2)
```

For the reverse:

```
torch.cat(t.split(32, dim=2), dim=3)
```

In general, the `dim` for `torch.split` tells which dimension you want to split over, and the `dim` for `torch.cat` tells which dimension you want to concatenate over.

Comment: and how to turn it back into  32x512 from 128x128?

Comment: Could you please add How would it change for [some, some, 32, 512]?

Comment: @DuckQueen Just change the `dim` from 1 to 3, since 512 is now the third dimension.

Comment: Seems like not: please see [link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ZyNZmTFekpAZVS1RPgtExOYrq1g8JOJ0?usp=sharing)

Comment: @DuckQueen Sorry, I had made a mistake in the arguments. Fixed it now.

Comment: Greate! And how hstack would change for [some, some, 128, 128] -> [some, some, 32, 512]?

Answer (score 1):

with numpy

```
np.vstack(np.hsplit(arr, 4))
```

and back:

```
np.hstack(np.vsplit(arr1, 4))
```